# Error Code 34 twitter_oauth 4.9 Gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-oauth

We had to update the twitter_oauth gem to v.0.4.9 to support Twitter's new 1.1 API. However, Favoriting posts and Following users doesn't work. I'm getting a return error when trying to follow a user or favorite a post as follows:

```
{"errors"=>[{"message"=>"Sorry, that page does not exist", "code"=>34}]}
```

I have an api_client model with the following:

```
def follow(id)
  client.friend(id)
end
```

My controller code:

```
def update
status = if params[:follow] 
  client.follow(params[:id])
elsif params[:follow] == 'false'
  client.follow(params[:id])
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.json do
    if status['screen_name'] == params[:screen_name]
      success = true
      notice = if params[:follow] == 'true'
        "You are now following #{status['screen_name']}"
      else
        "You are no longer following #{status['screen_name']}"
      end
    else
      success = false
      notice = 'Something went wrong. Try again in a couple of seconds.'
    end
    render :json => {:success => success, :message => notice}.to_json
  end
end
end
```

Has anyone else experienced this problem or can help me figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was the gem itself. The current 0.4.9 version of the gem is a work in progress and some of the post paths were not reflective of the new API. I have forked the repo and submitted my changes to the author for review. The changes I needed were to the favorites.rb and friendships.rb files in the gem. Here are the four changes I made to the gem:

**favorites.rb**

```
def favorite(id)
-  post("/favorites/create/#{id}.json")
+  post("/favorites/create.json?id=#{id}")
end

def unfavorite(id)
-  post("/favorites/destroy/#{id}.json")
+  post("/favorites/destroy.json?id=#{id}")
end
```

**friendships.rb**

```
def friend(id)
-  post("/friendships/create/#{id}.json")
+  post("/friendships/create.json?user_id=#{id}&follow=true")
end

def unfriend(id)
-  post("/friendships/destroy/#{id}.json")
+  post("/friendships/destroy.json?user_id=#{id}")
end
```